# ffprobe output mismatch between duration and number of read frames

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe, m2ts

I am currently trying to learn a bit about multimedia containers, notably M2TS. To get a lot of information about the tracks that are contained in such files in a human readable format, I found the following command very convenient:

```
"c:\program files\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe" -print_format json -loglevel fatal -show_entries format:packet:stream -show_streams -count_frames -i input.m2ts > output.json
```

In the resulting JSON file, there are entries for the duration of each audio track as well as for the number of audio frames (among others). However, when computing the duration of an audio track from the number of frames read, I get another result than the duration in the JSON file.

An example (unimportant lines replaced by `...`):

```
...
       {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "dts",
            "codec_long_name": "DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics)",
            "profile": "DTS-HD MA",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_tag_string": "[134][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0086",
            "sample_fmt": "s32p",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 8,
            "channel_layout": "7.1",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "initial_padding": 0,
            "ts_packetsize": "192",
            "id": "0x1100",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 1048560,
            "start_time": "11.650667",
            "duration_ts": 5247360,
            "duration": "58.304000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "nb_read_frames": "5467",
            "nb_read_packets": "5467",
            ...
        },
...
```

Here is my problem:

This is a DTSHD-MA audio track. Hence, there are `93.750 frames/s`. According to the JSON output, there are `5467 frames`. The duration then should be `(5467 / 93.750) = 58.315 s`.

However, the duration according to the JSON output is `58.304 s`.

The situation is similar with the other audio tracks in that file, and also with other audio tracks in other M2TS files. I can't imagine that every file I have test is corrupt or has errors; every file I have looked into is a MT2S file from a professionally mastered Blu-Ray disc (HD, not UHD).

Can somebody please explain where the difference comes from? What am I missing?

Comment: It's possible that the last audio frame is shorter that the other "nominal" frames. It is also possible that the `"duration"` tag (58.304) is not supper accurate (I don't know how accurate it is in MT2S files).

Comment: Thank for your comment. I don't believe that the last audio frame is just shorter, because the difference is quite exactly a complete audio frame (a frame of DTSHD-MA takes about 11 ms, which exactly is the difference). It smells like a off-by-one error in ffmpeg or like a misunderstanding on my side.

Comment: Not my expretee... You may try encoding you own file for testing: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -filter_complex "[0:a][0:a][0:a][0:a][0:a][0:a]amix=inputs=6" -c:a dca -frame_size 512 -ar 48000 -ac 6 -strict -2 -t 58.314666666 test.m2ts`. The output has 5467 frames. Packet duration is `960/90000` (applies 93.750 frames/s). Stream duration is marked as `58.304`. When setting `-t 0.106666666666667` (10 frames) the duration is marked as `0.096` for 10 frames.  It looks like the duration is short by one audio frame...

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I'll have to read some docs before I understand what's going on there. Of course, in my output I have noticed that the duration in seconds is exactly `duration_ts / time_base`: `5247360 / 90000 = 58.304`. But that doesn't match the `nb_read_frames`. Either the `nb_read_frames` is too high by `1`, or the `duration_ts` is too low by the duration of one audio frame. Or there is a weird time shift in the audio track (e.g. two frames start at the same time so that one of them is "lost" and doesn't add to the duration); I can hardly imagine that, though. Giving up on that one ...